# Issue with generating screenshots using Selenium and multithreading in Windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, thread-safety, windows-services

I am currently working on a Windows service that utilizes Selenium to capture screenshots. The screenshot generation process involves a multithreaded solution, where I use a Parallel.ForEach loop with 4 or more threads in each iteration. However, I am encountering an error after some time, even though the service initially runs without any issues.

Here is the error message that I receive:

> 2023-05-10 09:45:37.202 +00:00;;[INF];[T-];Unexpected Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:51961/session/ea521700fe9032a7c342c5da4ebfd806/window/rect. The exception message was: An error occurred while sending the request.
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.

I suspect that there might be an issue with the stability of my code. Could someone please help me identify the problem and suggest a solution to stabilize the code?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
Task<ChromeDriver> PrepareDriverAsync(int portValue)
{
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments(new List<string> { "--headless", "--hide-scrollbars" });
    options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;
    ChromeDriverService service = await CreateChromeDriverServiceAsync();
    service.Port = portValue;
    var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
    return driver;
}

Task<ChromeDriverService> CreateChromeDriverServiceAsync()
{
    ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = null;
    try
    {
        chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        // Code to handle exceptions or retries can be added here
    }
    catch (DriverServiceNotFoundException)
    {
        // Code to handle exceptions or retries can be added here
    }
    return chromeDriverService;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to stabilize my code and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Full code can be read here
https://codeshare.io/QneYzm

Comment: Please include more information about where in your code this exception is being thrown.

Comment: To be honest, I've found the only way to recover from this is to kill the ChromeDriver process and start over. Once the driver loses connection, it's over. Done. Whatever you were doing has ended. The best thing you can do is attempt to save info so you can respawn the driver, and continue somewhere close to where you left off.